# Lost endpoints after Spring Boot 3 migration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

After migrating dependencies from Spring Boot 2.6 to 3.2, switching from javax to jakarta, ..., I'm stuck because I cannot reach REST endpoints anymore. Request goes through filters but Spring cannot find corresponding endpoint :

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException: No endpoint GET /api/utilisateurs/current.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.noHandlerFound(DispatcherServlet.java:1304) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:6.0]
```

Here is the controller :

```
@Log4j2
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api/utilisateurs")
public class UtilisateurController {


    @GetMapping("/current")
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public ResponseEntity<UtilisateurConnecteDTO> getCurrentUser() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(SecurityUtils.getCurrentUtilisateur());
    }

}
```

And the security configuration :

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final ArenaFilter arenaFilter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                // Cross-Site Request Forgery disabling
                .csrf((csrf) -> csrf
                        .disable()
                        )//
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())//
                .addFilterBefore(arenaFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                // Session Management configuration (no creation -> stateless)
                .sessionManagement(sm -> sm.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
                http
                // Request authorization
                .authorizeHttpRequests(at -> at.requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()//
                        .requestMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()//
                .anyRequest().authenticated());
                http.headers(h -> h.frameOptions(fr -> fr.sameOrigin()));
                http.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
                return http.build();
    }
    
}
```

And Web configuration :

```
@Log4j2
@Configuration
public class WebConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter(ApplicationProperties applicationProperties) {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = applicationProperties.getCors();
        // Si la configuration Cors n'est pas complète, on ne l'applique pas.
        if (corsConfiguration.getAllowedOrigins() != null && !corsConfiguration.getAllowedOrigins().isEmpty()) {
            log.debug("Enregistrement du filtre CORS");
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/**", corsConfiguration);
        } else {
            log.debug("Pas de configuration CORS fournie");
        }
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }

    @Bean(name = "mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector")
    public HandlerMappingIntrospector mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector() {
        return new HandlerMappingIntrospector();
    }
}
```

I didn't modify the application behaviour, only translated code to Spring Boot 3 syntax and beans. Controllers are in a submodule of the app

Any idea why all endpoints are not loaded at startup ?

Comment: Can you try `@GetMapping("current")`?

Comment: Can you share your app configuration?

Comment: Why did you define the `HandlerMappingIntrospector` as it is already added by Spring.

Comment: @M. Deinum : There seemed to be a bug in early 3.x version that needed defining manually the bean. However it did not change anything

Comment: @knittl no difference

Comment: @Alex_X1 yes I can, but which one do you need ?

Comment: @Biologeek is your controller picked up by the component scan and registered in your application context? Are other controllers affected too?

Comment: Indeed controllers are found and dependencies are injected : 

o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'indicateurController'
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Autowiring by type from bean name 'indicateurController' via constructor to bean named 'indicateurServiceImpl'
DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Autowiring by type from bean name 'indicateurController' via constructor to bean named 'indicateurMapperImpl'

Comment: However, comparing with v2.6, other annotations (Spring web MVC ones in particular) are not processed